# Flutter FCM on iOS not calling onMessage and onResume

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I was testing FCM for flutter on an iOS device, i followed the guides and i can successfully send notification to my iOS device, the problem is that when i touch the notification neither onResume is not being called, also if the app is in foreground onMessage is not called either. However if the app is closed it does trigger onLaunch

I wonder how can i fix this? or if anyone else is having this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that i was using another plugin for handling local notifications(flutter_local_notifications) and it was causing conflict with firebase messaging(the plugin says that in the Readme file), so i removed flutter_local_notifications and firebase messaging started to work as intended

Comment: was wondering if you've tested this on Android, and if yes, do they also conflict on Android?

Comment: yes i tested on android but i didn't have any problems

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

in ios/Runner/info.plist?